What are some options for making gravel come out of a chute?

I have a chute that I want gravel to come out of. The whole machine is going to be rendered about 175x200 from a top-down oblique camera. The gravel is going to fall on spinning blades that "grind" the gravel down. The operation is going to be too small for "breaking" animations, but the gravel should interact with the blades.
I have tried :

Using fluid simulation. I got it bouncing off the blades, but I can't get it "chunky" and the texture I am using never appears (probably because I don't know how to apply a uv map to a fluid. I read somewhere that it can't be done.)
Using rigidbodies, I can create a single rock in a way I could scale to a pile, but I can't give it velocity in any controlled way. I tried using animation frames, but it REALLY doesn't like switching from animated to physics simulation, and it rockets away in a (seemingly) random direction.

The optimal solution would be something that could loop, but that is a secondary concern right now.
What technique or tool should I use, or how can I fix the problems with my previous attempts? Should I convert the fluid to many little rocks? How would I do that?

My first thought is a particle simulation.

Correct that one can’t UV map a fluid, it’s an always changing mesh so there’s no way to map it unless one somehow did it for every frame separately. You CAN apply a 3D procedural texture with space mapped coordinates, but it probably won’t look right for this.

Per TheLabCat's comment, I tried a particle system solution. It takes a lot of tuning to the physics variables to get the right behavior, but I eventually found good values. In physics > forces

Brownian 3.190
Drag 0.221
Damp 0.178

With these, rotation enabled, and all of the relevant objects given collision physics, and giving a instance object in Render > Object > Instance Object, the result is excellent.
